# Does sighting Northern lights have any significance in Hinduism?

Tags: philosophy, belief

I visited a place in the western world during this summer where I got to witness the Northern lights/Aurora Borealis (if there is the right kind of atmosphere and the sky is clear and if we’re lucky enough).

I wanted to know whether there is any significance of viewing an uncommon/rare natural phenomenon in Hinduism? Does this have any effect (positive or spiritually) on our lives?

Answer (score 2):

"Ramayana, believed to have happened almost 2 million years ago on earth, was written by sage Valmiki and it describes almost entire geography of earth in all directions.
In Kishkinda Kanda episode of Ramayana, Vanara king Sungreeva’s plans to send 4 teams in 4 directions to find Seetha, who was kidnapped by Ravana (revealed later).
At that point of time, they had no idea in which direction she must have been taken.

One such team headed from Jambudwipa (India) towards the North is given a route-map by Sugreeva, which would lead them right across the mountains of China, the plateau of Mongolia, Lake Baikaal of Siberia and then the path along the Angara River northwards to the Kara Sea of the Arctic Ocean where the search is supposed to end.
These ‘vanaras‘ are instructed to travel right up to ‘Northern Lights or Aurora Borealis‘ of Siberia and the Arctic Ocean", https://www.booksfact.com/mysteries/northern-lights-or-aurora-borealis-siberia-china-in-ramayana.html